# When FFT fails to perform circular convolution?

Tags: fft, convolution

I need to know of the applications that circular convolution is needed but FFT can not be used or FFT's convolution property fails.

Comment: Multiplying the DFT (the FFT is a fast DFT) of something by a vector of weights in the frequency domain, then doing an inverse DFT _always_ results in a circular convolution of your starting vector.  That's just how the math works.  So the FFT circular convolution property always holds.

Comment: Yes that is correct, but I am looking at situations in for example digital comm applications that a external parameter such as time-varying distortions can cause issues for DFT not to be able to perform circular convolution.

Comment: as said, no matter what you do, the result is a cricular convolution between the two vectors. There's nothing changing that – what you're asking is literally "under which circumstances does a circular convolution not pose a circular convolution", and the answer is "under no circumstances, these are identical"

Comment: It sounds like what you're asking then is "When does the use of circular convolution not _apply_ when it otherwise might".  Which is a pretty big reach - usually one doesn't want to do circular convolution, and when using the FFT to implement a filter you take pains to choose a combination of data chunk size, FFT size, and filter size that allows you to use overlap-and-add, *not* circular convolution.

Comment: Well you are all correct. My question is systematically wrong. In OFDM circular convolution plays an important role in converting a frequency selective channel to a flat fading channel. But when the channel becomes time varying during a symbol period then OFDM subcarriers lose their orthogonality. Yes it does not have anything to do with circular convolution. Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes (very rare), circular convolution may be more complexity efficient when compared to FFT. Let us say we circ-convolve to two arrays with lengths of $N$ and $K$, respectively.
Recall that circular convolution can be performed with $N\times K$ operations.
On the other hand, to perform circular convolution with the help of FFT, you need to run the FFT algorithm 2 times and IFFT once, resulting in $3N\log_2(N)$ (Assuming $N>K$. If $N\times K$ is less than $3N\log_2(N)$, directly applying circular convolution is computationally efficient.

NOTE:  Performing circular convolution with the FFT algorithm causes some truncation errors due to finite precision.

Comment: regarding your last note: nope, doing circular convolution using FFTs is actually *more* numerically stable than straightforward convolution!

Comment: Even two real signals are circ-convolved by using FFT, the resulting signal contains complex parts. These imaginary parts are due to truncation. Actually, that was the point I was trying to emphasize. Thank you for the correction!

Comment: the imaginary part is an error, but the total error of a FFT-based circular convolution over floating point numbers is **smaller** than that of a "classical" convolution using floating point numbers. Also, you can use real-to-complex and complex-to-real FFTs (which are slightly more efficient than full FFTs) and don't even get to see the imaginary part. (by the way, the errors do *not* happen due to truncation, typically, but due to "proper" rounding, but that's really a semantical detail)